# How to use tokens in 3-tier web-app using WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, authorization, wcf-security, 3-tier

Good day. I've looked all over for an example of how to do this, and while I have found all sorts of useful info on how to implement bits of it, the overall solution still eludes me.

I have a 3-tier web-based application (Presentation tier is Web Forms, business/DAL tier is a WCF web service, DB is Oracle) for which I want to implement an Authorization/Authentication mechanism.

My thought was to use the Enterprise Library Securty block to generate a token in the WCF service (and cache it there), and send the token id back to the web-app server. The token id would be sent back to the client browser (via a cookie) and then all subsequent requests back to the WCF service I would pass this token id in the header of the request message. I would then use some of the WCF extensibility interfaces to check for authentication by looking for the id in the cache. I was also going to cache the roles (I'm just using simple role based access) with the token so that I had in-memory access to the roles list for the user and I could avoid a DB round-trip for every access check.

Does this part make sense as to the right way to go? If so, here is the second part.

Now my problem is how to manage role access and session management from the webserver hosting the presentation tier. I'm managing the roles from the business layer, but I also need access to them in the presentation layer because I also wanted to use role-based access to each page via the web.configs. How do I do this? should I also pass the roles back to this layer? There is something smelly about both the service and the webapp having to store versions of this rolelist.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I should have pointed out that I will have internet users accessing one web app server, with internal LAN users accessing another web app server, both accessing the same WCF service. For the internal users I will be authenticating with Active Directory, as well as having a user record in a custom table in the Oracle DB. I figured I could just pass in an indicator as to whether the caller was internal or external (or just not pass in a password) but it might be a new wrinkle in the above problem.